# An element is not removed from the array, how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs

I have data that I get from api and through the map() method I display these "cards", each card has an image when clicked on which this image should receive an additional class. I implemented this by adding the index of the card to an array and now I can assign new classes to them, but I can't delete them

P.S. I have strict mode enabled, if it is disabled it removes extra classes on all other cards except the one I clicked on

```
//On the first click, it adds to the array, on the second click, it must delete it (index is written to the array)
function toggleFavoriteChanel(index) {
          setFavorite(prevState => {
             let returnArray = prevState;
             if(prevState.includes(index)){
              console.log(prevState)
              console.log(index)
                return returnArray.splice(prevState.indexOf(index), 1)
             }else{
                // here are 3 dots
                return [..returnArray, index]
             }
          })
      }

//  <img src={star} alt="star".../>
{Array.isArray(props.visibleData) ? props.visibleData.map((chanel, index) => {
                        return (
                            <>
                                <div className="chanel__item" key={index}>
                                    <img src={star} alt="star" onClick={() => props.toggleFavoriteChanel(index)} id={index} className={`star ${props.favorite.includes(index)  ? 'active' : ''}`} />
                                    <NavLink
                                        onClick={() => props.updateData(index)}
                                        end
                                        style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}
                                        to='/ChanelPage'>
                                    <img src={chanel.image} alt="" className="chanel__img" />
                                    <div className="chanel__title"><div className="chanel__item-number">{index + 1}. &nbsp;</div>{chanel.name_ru}</div>
                                    </NavLink>
                                </div> 
                            </>
                        ) 
                    }) : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are setting `favorite` to the return value of `splice`, which is an array containing the deleted elements (from [MDN docs on splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#return_value)). What you want instead is to return `returnArray` after calling `splice` on it.

Just change this line in `toggleFavoriteChanel`:

```
return returnArray.splice(prevState.indexOf(index), 1)
```

to:

```
returnArray.splice(prevState.indexOf(index), 1);
return returnArray;
```

---

While the above should fix your issue, I would recommend approaching this problem in a different way if you are just trying to toggle a CSS class in response to clicking (assuming you don't need a list of the favorited cards at a higher level).

The approach is to define a component for the card and hold the `isFavorite` (clicked) state locally rather than in an array in an ancestral component.

Here's a rough example:

```
function Card(props) {
    const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = React.useState(false);
    
    return (
        <div className="chanel__item">
            <img
                src={star}
                alt="star"
                onClick={() => setIsFavorite(prev => !prev)}
                id={props.index}
                className={`star ${isFavorite ? 'active' : ''}`}
            />
            <NavLink
                onClick={() => props.updateData(props.index)}
                end
                style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}
                to='/ChanelPage'>
            <img src={chanel.image} alt="" className="chanel__img" />
            <div className="chanel__title"><div className="chanel__item-number">{props.index + 1}. &nbsp;</div>{props.chanel.name_ru}</div>
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    )
}
```